# Regex to capture data

Tags: regex

I am trying to capture a set of strings using regular expressions.
The strings are of the following format

```
CID _At                   1   2  99   1,198,498,377         414           0       0       0       3,694
```

The expression that I came up with is

```
[A-Za-z][a-z0-9A-Z_-]*\s*[0-6]\s*[0-4]\s\s[\s\d]\d\s*[0-9,]*\s*[0-9,]*\s*[0-9,]*\s*[0-9,]*\s*0\s*[0-9,]*
```

Although this expression works for me,and gives the necessary output ,I feel that it is not optimized .

Can someone help me optimize the expression ?

Comment: You can play with the regex here: https://regex101.com/r/86DiBO/1 It also shows you how many steps are needed.

Comment: Hi @jace I am trying to extract data from a file .The file contains multiple rows similar to the one I mentioned ,with different values and names ,and also some other data which I do not need.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$text = 'CID _At                   1   2  99   1,198,498,377         414           0       0       0       3,694';
preg_match("/^[A-Z]+\s+[A-Za-z_]+\s+[0-9]+\s+[0-9]+\s+[0-9]+\s+[0-9,]+\s+[0-9]+\s+[0-9]+\s+[0-9]+\s+[0-9]+\s+[0-9,]+$/", $text, $m);
print_r($m);
preg_match("/^([A-Z]+)\s+([A-Za-z_]+)\s+([0-9]+)\s+([0-9]+)\s+([0-9]+)\s+([0-9,]+)\s+([0-9]+)\s+([0-9]+)\s+([0-9]+)\s+([0-9]+)\s+([0-9,]+)$/", $text, $m);
print_r($m);
/*
Output:
Array
(
    [0] => CID _At                   1   2  99   1,198,498,377         414           0       0       0       3,694
)
Array
(
    [0] => CID _At                   1   2  99   1,198,498,377         414           0       0       0       3,694
    [1] => CID
    [2] => _At
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 2
    [5] => 99
    [6] => 1,198,498,377
    [7] => 414
    [8] => 0
    [9] => 0
    [10] => 0
    [11] => 3,694
)

*/
```

remove the * and if you need group the internal matches with ()
example in php, if you need some length, replace "+" by "{1}" (1 char length)

if you need, minimum 1 and max 3 {1,3}

if you need minimum 1 and maximum infinite {1,}